# Job condition based on path

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is it possible to have a condition based on the paths, similar to Trigger? Within my pipeline, I only want to run a particular job if a certain folder has changed.

**I read this document and found no reference**

[Pipeline Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

[Pipeline Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Hi, does your puzzle could be solved with @4c74356b41 's answer?  If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some issues please leave a comment so we can still help you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have a path based trigger on your build, not on the job.

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include: [ string ] # file paths which must match to trigger a build
    exclude: [ string ] # file paths which will not trigger a build
```

technically there is a `Build.Reason` automatic variable, that might be available at build queue time to determine that, but you'd have to only have the path triggers for this to work, in my opinion

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables

Comment: this suggestion does not solve, my goal is to execute 3/4 build jobs when the xpto/* folder is not changed, otherwise run all 4 jobs

Comment: this is not possible, you'd have to use git log and parse the output with a script

Comment: Can this functionality be added to the pipeline?

Comment: you can raise a user voice item for this or vote for that item (if it's already there). unfortunately I'm typing this on my phone so I can't give you a url